# Understanding the CNY70 Reflective Optical Sensor

Tags: sensor, phototransistor

As far as I know, TM4C123 LaunchPad safely accepts voltages values up to 3.3V . I got a CNY70 reflective optical sensor and want to connect it to one of the analog input ports safely as in the attachment. (each of +5V comes from 5V AC to DC adapter)

[image]

The main problem is that I don't understand much from the CNY70's [datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83751/cny70.pdf).  (I couldn't find anything about the ON state resistance of the transistor, which could make things much easier for me)

Could you please explain what calculations should I do, or which figures should I check in the data sheet in order to calculate the X resistance value for safe operation.

P.S: Please keep in mind that, I'm quite a newbie in electronics

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transistor does not behave like a resistor. It's more like a current source until Vce drops to below a volt or so. The relevant curves from the datasheet (specified with a known reflectance) are below:

[image]

You have about 20mA going through the LED (a bit much for my liking), so the typical CTR is about 5% (Figure 7). That means that a typical unit will pass about 1mA through the transistor. If your resistor X is high enough (more than 4K or so, **typically**) then the CTR will be much lower (Figure 8). The transistor will bottom out at 100mV or so. The voltage will be If * CTR/100 * Rx.

If your application does not have the 0.3mm spacing then Figure 11 comes into play- so the voltage will be If * CTR/100 * Rx * Icrel

[image]

Comment: Did you use Fig. 3 to calculate forward voltage and current?

Comment: I could have, but I happen to know the Vf of an infrared LED is close enough to 1.2V at 20mA, so I didn't.

Comment: It's 100%  safe (as in nothing will be damaged)- it might saturate or not at high reflectance, depending. There is only a typical 1mA a minimum 0.3mA and no maximum (very loose specifications). I would guess that most units are between 0.3 and 3mA under the specified conditions (0.3mm Kodak card, 20mA).

Comment: Edit: Accidentaly removed my question: "Is it safe to use 3K resistor for operation"

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't think of "on state resistance" of a bipolar transistor.

For opto couplers and similar items, such as this, you should look at the Current Transfer Ratio (CTR).  This indicates how much current the transistor should pass, for a given LED current.  For the CNY70, the CTR is illustrated by Fig. 5.

In the "Basic Characteristics" table, the first line indicates that the typical transistor current is 1 mA with an LED current of 20 mA, when viewing a white card.

Comment: Wish I could have enough reputation to upvote. Today with your help, I learned that there are photoresistors around and work quite different than bipolar transistors :) Thank you