# Why does CNY70 output peak at a distance only?

Tags: phototransistor, light-sensor

I am using the CNY70 sensor similar as in [Understanding the CNY70 Reflective Optical Sensor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179115/understanding-the-cny70-reflective-optical-sensor) (FTR: V=3.3V (instead of 5V) R=1k (instead of 200Ω) and X=10k putting the output voltage in the range of 0–0.9V in my measurements):

[image]

If I read the [datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83751/cny70.pdf) correctly, I would assume that collector current (and thus voltage across the resistor X) peaks when a reflective surface is at 0mm distance:

[image]

However in my experiments this is not the case. Voltage peaks at a distance of ~3mm and then sharply declines.

I couldn’t find an explanation for this (other than not using the Kodak paper). I tried this with different surfaces and it reproduces consistently. Any ideas?

[image]

- x axis: distance to plain white paper (left: 10cm, right: 0mm, not a linear scale)
- y axis: measured voltage

Answer (score 1):

There's some distance between the emmitter and detector and probably some plastic web in between to prevent a false direct path.

When your reflector is *too close* it likely reflects the light of the emitter mostly back onto the emitter with very little making it over to the detector; it has to be a little further away for the geometry to allow the detector to directly "see" the emitter.

Comment: Yes, that’s very intuitive, but that doesn’t describe the discrepancy to the datasheet.